# Yocto Language support

Tags: localization, qt5, yocto, imx6

I'm am working on a yocto project ( imx6 based ) with Qt5. 
I need my image to support "Hebrew" out of the box, as well as English.
Any Idea ?

Thanks, 
Ran

Answer (score 0):

So, Language support doesn't need any BSP specific changes or Yocto specific changes. You can include it in the Qt app with Qt linguistic support. This might be helpful to you to solve linguistic problem. [Qt Linguistic.](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/internationalization.html). As they are officially supporting hebrew as well. I am not sure which qt Version you are using but this will surely help to make some decision. You can also enable language packages plugins by updating recipes in Yocto but it would be good to have Qt linguistic approach.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for the reply.
So the scenario is as follows :